# Dismissing view in UINavigationController and at the same time syncing

Tags: ios, objective-c, api

There's two views on a NavigationController stack:

1. EDIT ITEM-DETAILS VIEW (= basically a form)
2. SHOW ALL ITEMS IN A TABLE VIEW

I wonder if there are best practices for the task I have:

When the user taps "BACK" in the UINavigationController-bar (while being in view **1**) the app should update the item on the server.

That's not so difficult, but the BACK-action leads to view **2**, and **2** is not up-to date, because the update happened in the background and wasn't through before the GET-request for the table view data finished.

So in order to have view **2** always show accurate data, I have several options. All a bit annoying.. (for example having ViewController of view **2** talk to server on **1**'s behalf and update itself when completed, or having a "update happened" notification that triggers a reload, ...)

But.. what's a good best-practice for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would make a central place for the Items. Lets call it a ItemsStore. ItemsStore is a singleton that has the responsibility to have a set of the latest items and give access to the items. It also fires notifications if new data arrives, or old data is saved.

In this case:

- View 2 adds the data to the store. The store notifies that there are
  changes.
- View 1 updates on the notification.
- View 2 also asks the ItemsStore to
  save the data to the server.

I would not give the responsibility of loading and saving to the controllers, it will get ugly and complex.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly the sort of input I was hoping for. I'll have to think this particular suggestion through. After all this would introduce some extra overhead. For example the singleton ItemsStore would in turn have to notify to controllers that it just fetched new data. I'll have to think if I can implement this cleanly.