# After "popViewControllerAnimated" method calls second method

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigation controller. On the second view of this controller I have created a back button which action named "back". In this method I call "popViewControllerAnimated" method and problem is, that after "popViewControllerAnimated", I have some other action which is also called in the same time, but **after** "popViewControllerAnimated" and they are show to me, but I need to block it.

When I press button:

```
- (void)back {
     [socketIO sendEvent:@"exit" withData:nil]; // Send data to server
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

And the delegate for parsing the result from server:

```
- (void)socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet {
    if ([packet.name isEqualToString:@"disconnect"]) {
         NSLog(@"Exit"); // This code also works, but it works after "popViewControllerAnimated", but I want to block it.
    }
}
```

**Scheme**:

1. User press back
2. App send to server event "exit"
3. popViewControllerAnimated
4. App received the answer from server and show result

But how the item 4 in list works after "popViewControllerAnimated", if I closed that View Controller? How I can fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you place the communication logic in a central class (probably a singleton)? That has the responsibility to communicate with the backend. When it receives an answer, it sends a notification. Some class should receive the notification and add a new view controller.

Something like what I suggested in this thread: [Dismissing view in UINavigationController and at the same time syncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275431/dismissing-view-in-uinavigationcontroller-and-at-the-same-time-syncing/17277353#17277353)

--- Edit to respond to comment ---
First of all I think it is important that the name of the class below is more connected to the problem you are trying to solve. I gave it a general name, but I'm not happy with the name I choose.

```
@interface Communicator : NSObject

- (void) sendExit;

+ (Communication *) defaultCommunicator;

@end
```

In the .c

```
- (void)socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet {
    if ([packet.name isEqualToString:@"disconnect"]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CommunicatorExit" object:boek];

    }
}
```

A good place for listening to the notification would be the view controller before the current one.

Comment: I use singleton, but I use it for connect with server, but it isn't comfortable to work with view controller from singleton. Or you can show an example how it can be clearly done?